# Why does "null" increase length of an array even though it represents empty value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When "null" is included in the items in an array it counts in the length of the array. But "null" should mean no value. Then why does it happen?

```js
var myArray = ["pizza", "burger", null];

var test = function (input) {
 return input.length;
};
document.write(test(myArray));
```

Comment: An empty box is still a box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The value null represents the **intentional absence** of any object value. It is one of JavaScript's primitive values.

It is not completely absent, that is **intentional** absence, which means that someone wants a null value at the position and use/update it later.

`null` have a unique meaning

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

Answer (score 2):

It's because null is also an value.
null represents the intentional absence of any object value

See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

Answer (score 1):

In Layman's term, It's an empty box which is supposed to contain something.
When you are adding null to an array, consider as you are adding an empty box in a larger container.

Answer (score 0):

because null is a reference but it refers to nothing, but it still consumes space